# Swift - `self` in variable initialization closure

Tags: swift, swift4, self

How does `button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(taptap), for: .touchUpInside)`
 work without a `lazy` keyword?

Dropped `lazy` by mistake, and have a closure to initialize a button like below:

```
class MyView: UIView {

    let button: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(taptap), for: .touchUpInside)
        print(self) // (Function)
        // button.frame = bounds <- Cannot assign here
        return button
    }()

    lazy var button2: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        print(self) // <sample.MyView ...>
        return button
    }()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        addSubview(button2)
        addSubview(button)
        button.frame = bounds
        print(self) // <sample.MyView ...>
    }

    @objc func taptap() {
        print("taptap")
    }
}
```

And the printed result is:

```
(Function)
<sample.MyView: 0x7f961dd09d80; frame = (67 269; 240 128); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x6080000268a0>>
<sample.MyView: 0x7f961dd09d80; frame = (67 269; 240 128); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x6080000268a0>>
taptap
```

What's the difference `self` in button closure and `self` in others? And why my button is works?

Comment: Lazy property is get called once you initialize not before that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works in `NSObject` subclasses because `NSObject` (or rather `NSObjectProtocol`) declares method [self](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418956-nsobject/1418954-self?language=objc). That method is also available on metatypes (which are also `NSObject` instances) and therefore you can call it in static context.

The fact that it actually works on `UIButton` is probably a quirk of the compiler and the fact that `UIButton` accepts `Any?` as target.

Don't use it, it's not how it's intended to work.

See the bug [SR-4559](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-4559?jql=text%20~%20%22self%20function%22)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You saved my time.

Answer (score 2):

In short, when you declare an instance property using closure initialization, that property will be created before `self` would be available (before the instance had been initalized properly), hence you cannot access `self`. A `lazy` instance property can only ever be accessed after the instance had been initalized, so you can access `self` from a `lazy` propery.

Longer version:

If you use closure initializiation by `let button: UIButton = { return UIButton() }()`, the `button` variable will be handled the exact same way in runtime as if you simply declared it like `let button:UIButton = UIButton()`. Pay attention to the `()` at the end of the closure. That essentially executes the closure right away when the instance property is being initialized, this is why it can actually be declared as immutable. Since instance properties are being initialized before the class initializer would be called, `self` is not available inside the closure for of a property.

When you declare a variable using the `lazy` keyword, it will only be evaluated when it is first accessed. Due to this, `self` is available inside the closure declaring a `lazy` property, since a property cannot be **accessed** before the class instance would be created, so in all cases, `self` is already initialized and available by the time you'd ever access the lazy property.